# How do you "leave all the beefin' to 50"?

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang, lyrics

How does someone *"leave all the beefin' to 50"*?

**Context**

From the latest song by [Richard Colson Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Gun_Kelly_(rapper)) ["Rap Devil"](https://genius.com/Machine-gun-kelly-rap-devil-lyrics)

> Let's leave all the beefin' to 50 (please)
>   Em, you're pushin' 50

You can find a [video of the song here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp0BScQSSvg).

Comment: Song lyrics can be difficult to interpret. So you may get very opinionated answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the lyrics in your link, the rapper seems to be talking to Eminem, and name-dropping lots of other rappers. In this context the first "50" is probably the rapper "Fifty Cent"

Hence "Let's leave all the beefin' to 50" would mean:

> Let Fifty Cent get angry and complain at people, let's not do that ourselves

In the next line I think "50" is more likely to be an age, so "Em, you're pushing 50" would mean:

> Eminem, you're nearly fifty years old

There is a slight chance that it's still talking about Fifty Cent, in which case my only guess is:

> Eminem, you're pushing Fifty Cent close to the edge of his anger limit

Comment: *Without full context* There's the link to the lyrics to "Rap Devil"? Ha! The meaning of the phrase is explained if you click on the lyrics.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks, I'm now more certain about the first "50", but still not really sure about the "pushing 50".